# Passing scope through an angularjs directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I want to create a reusable directive that passes the parent scope through the directive to it's child scope.

For example, I want to dynamically set the height of a container so that it can be scrollable. The problem is that any of the items that I want to be repeated (in this case the log) I must pass in to the scrollable directive since once I add it anything contained within is in the scrollable scope.

The problem comes in when I want to reuse the scrollable directive on a container that doesn't have a need for the log parameter (or needs many types of logs). Is there a way to have the inner ngRepeat reach outside of the directive scope? Or have the directive map the parent's scope on to it's own?

My HTML follows. Note that I must pass in the 'service.log' so that the ngRepeat knows what to iterate over.

```
<div ng-controller="LogCtrl" class="span3">
  <div scrollable log="service.log" selector="#stats-content" class="well">
    <h4>Log</h4>
    <dl ng-repeat="item in log">
      <dt>{{item.key}}</dt>
      <dd>{{item.value}}</dd>
    </dl>
  </div> <!-- well -->
```

My controller is pretty simple:

```
.controller('LogCtrl', function($scope, log_service) {
  $scope.service = log_service;
});
```

The scrollable directive:

```
.directive('scrollable', function(current) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      selector: '@',
      log: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
      var height = $(attrs.selector).height();
      elem.height(height - 300 + 'px');
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want. The `ng-repeat` has access to the parent scope, i.e. the scope of `LogCtrl`, if that's what you mean.

Comment: I also don't follow your question. Why dont you just use `ng-repeat="item in service.log"` ?

Comment: when you set "scope: {...}" you are telling the directive that it needs a private scope and not the inherited one it would normally use.
Read through this posting, especially the "Scope" section.

http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/directives.html

Comment: What I am seeing is that if I remove the isolate scope of log: '=', and change the ng-repeat to use service.log then nothing gets displayed. It appears that the ng-repeat doesn't have access to LogCtrl's service.log. I've create a plunkr to demonstrate what I'm seeing (check the comment in script.js) : http://plnkr.co/edit/SLdkUqLUyCKXEzAZAjwN?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what you need, you can use the `transclude` property of the **[directive definition object](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile#description_comprehensive-directive-api_directive-definition-object)** along with the **[`ngTransclude`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angTransclude)** directive. Quoting the docs:

> **`transcule`**
>   compile the content of the element and make it available to the directive. Typically used with ngTransclude. [...]
>   In a typical setup the widget creates an isolate scope, but the transclusion is not a child, but a **sibling** of the isolate scope. This makes it possible for the widget to have private state, and the transclusion to be bound to the **parent (pre-isolate) scope**.

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

This way, your directive does not need to know anything about parent scope's `service` (either `log` or nothing or whatever). It just makes the element scrollable, but the content of the element (including child elements with the `ng-repeat` directive) are bound to a non-isolate scope, which means it prototypically inherits the properties of the parent scope (including e.g. `service`).

---

Because it may first sound more complicated than it is, the modified code could look like this:

```
app.directive('scrollable', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            ...
            // I don't need to know anything about `log`
            // log: '='
        },
        transclude: true,                        // This and the next line
        template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',   // do the trick
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.css({
                border:   '1px solid gray',
                height:   '100px',
               overflow: 'auto'
            });
        }
    };
});
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/WyV5t/)**.

Comment: I had tried transclude: true, but forgot to include the template. Thanks!